# can i use where and order by in mysql together?

Tags: mysql

Can i use where and order by in mysql together like this

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT `status_content`
    FROM `status`
    WHERE `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']."
    ORDER BY `status_time` DESC" );
```

her is my code, but it is giving me error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\profile.php on line 65

```
<?php 
$results=mysql_query("SELECT status_content FROM status 
                      WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                      ORDER BY status_time DESC" );
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
    echo $row['status_content']; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Yes you can. You can always consult the documentation for such questions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.

Comment: Yes, but do you really need SO to find out the answer?

Comment: her is my code, but it is giving me error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\profile.php on line 65

Comment: <?php
 $results=mysql_query("SELECT `status_content` FROM `status` WHERE `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']."ORDER BY `status_time` DESC" );
 
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)){
  echo $row['status_content'];
  }
 
 ?>

Comment: If `mysql_query` returns false, it means that there is an error in your query or you don't have permission to access the table. This is also described in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is valid as google will tell you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

For your actual error, [from the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

```
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // do something
}
```

Also: you should **not use the mysql_* functions anymmore** since they are deprecated and unsafe.
Use [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instead.